# inequalities involving norm and probability

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $\sum_i^d{x_i}^2 \leq \sum_i^d{y_i}^2$. What can we say about $\sum_i^da_i^2x_i^2$, compared with $\sum_i^da_i^2y_i^2$. Clearly, as the number of dimensions, d, goes larger, then we can be more confident that $\sum_i^da_i^2x_i^2 \leq \sum_i^da_i^2y_i^2$. How can this be stated in a mathematical/probabilistic way? Also, suppose $x_i,y_i\in \mathbb{R}$, and $a_i \neq 0$, or make other assumptions if it is needed.

Suppose x=(1,1) and y=(4, 0), then the choice of (0.1, 1), would make $\sum_i^da_i^2x_i^2 > \sum_i^da_i^2y_i^2$. But if the number of dimensions was 100, then an a vector like (0.1, 0.1,...,1), with very small numbers for most dimensions, and a large number for one dimension would be very unlikely, considering a is from an assumed distribution.

Comment: What does "more confident" mean here?

Comment: Suppose $x_i$ and $y_i$ have disjoint support, and $a_i$ to be positive only on the support of $(y_i)_i$. Then $\sum_i a_ix_i^2 = 0 < \sum_i a_iy_i^2$, regardless of the dimension. This generalizes to $a_i > 0 $ for all $i$ by replacing $a_i=0$ by a sufficiently tiny value.